# Meteor: use dynamic parameters in a template call

Tags: validation, templates, meteor, internationalization, spacebars

In my Meteor app i have the `TAPi18n` package and `aldeed:autoform`. Im trying to make a form validation using i18n for the placeholder field but i don't know how to do it.

So, I was wondering if it is possible to pass a dynamic parameter (that's how I call it) to a template, using `Spacebars`. I mean, without using helpers in the JS files, something like this:

```html
<template name="Publish">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 well">
        {{#autoForm collection="Publications" id="insertPublicationForm" type="insert"}}
            <fieldset>
                <legend>{{_ "publish_title"}}</legend>

                <div  class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div  class="form-group">
                        {{> afFieldInput name='name' placeholder={{_ "name"}} }}
                    </div>

                    <div  class="form-group">
                        {{> afFieldInput name='description' placeholder={{_ "description"}} }}
                    </div>

                    <div  class="form-group">
                        {{> afFieldInput name='price' placeholder={{_ "price"}} }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div  class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="add_publication" class="btn btn-success center-block">{{_ "publish"}}</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        {{/autoForm}}
    </div>
</template>
```

I could register a helper for every translation but i don't like too much the idea.

I also know that i could use the label field in the `SimpleSchema`, like this:

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Publications.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            label: TAPi18n.__("name"),
            max: 200
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            label: TAPi18n.__("description")
        },
        price: {
            type: Number,
            label: TAPi18n.__("price"),
            min: 0
        }
    }));
});
```

And then use the `afQuickField` template instead of `afFieldInput`.
But i don't want to use a label, i want to use the placeholder of the input.

There is any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i don't know why i didn't see it before, but i can do this in the `SimpleSchema`:

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Publications.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            label: TAPi18n.__("name"),
            max: 200,
            autoform: {
                afFieldInput: {
                    placeholder: TAPi18n.__("name")
                }
            }
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            autoform: {
                afFieldInput: {
                    placeholder: TAPi18n.__("description")
                }
            }
        },
        price: {
            type: Number,
            min: 0,
            autoform: {
                afFieldInput: {
                    placeholder: TAPi18n.__("price")
                }
            }
        }
    }));
});
```

That way i can use i18n in the placeholder without making tons of helpers.

Sorry if I made someone waste time on this.